# Problems with Uninstalling program windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

Having issues with uninstalling Avast program from computer. Not sure what else I can do to remove the program. Used conventional methods such as 'Uninstall Program' from Control Panel as well as using 3rd party software to completely remove program however program seems to still be there and available to run however it is corrupted at the moment. 
Attempted to delete files using delete files from registry but program could not be found. Could not delete manually via %program files% either as it says I do not have permission although I am administrator. 
Also attempted using CCleaner to remove residue files but the files are still there in my program folders.

Looking for any advice on how to successfully remove this program so i can install a new version.

Please help!!

Many thanks in Advance

Comment: Try the Avast cleanup utility.  https://www.avast.com/uninstall-utility

Comment: I've tried that but it wont run. The loading page comes up but then it just stops and disappears. Same thing happens when i try re-installing